# Unable to enable Mobile HotSpot (Windows)

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, ethernet, tethering, pppoe

I have broadband (PPPoE) internet connection and I want to share it with my phone using WiFi. The problem is, Windows doesn't count PPPoE as Ethernet connection. Is there any ways to convince Windows that i actually have internet?
[image]

Comment: Buy a wireless router and connect to the internet using PPPoE on the router. Bonus: Your phone can now connect directly to the wireless router.

Comment: I'm looking for other solutions, without router

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: Nope. This bug still exists